# org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: java, json, json-simple

I want to retrieve cliendId and clientSecret into 2 different Strings.

I am trying to do

```
String responseEntity = secretRequestMap.get("responseEntity").toString();
```

to get the responseEntity into a string and then parse it again, using JSON parser, but it throws an exception in thread "main":

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to java.lang.String.
```

When I inspect it doesn't show any error but when I run it throws exception. Please help.

```
String response = {"statusCode":"200","responseEntity":{"clientId":"abc","clientSecret":"xyz"},"errorList":[]};
Map<String, String> responseMap  = (Map<String, String>) new JSONParser().parse(response);
```

Comment: So do you see anywhere where it says that `toString` is a method of `JSONObject`?

Comment: @HotLicks `toString()` is a method of all `Object`s

Comment: You can't get a runtime exception... `String response = {"statusCode":"200"` does not compile...

Comment: `String responseEntity = (String)secretRequestMap.get("responseEntity").toString(); `

Answer (score 2):

cast it by using `(String)` because it will return as an Object.

```
String responseEntity =(String) secretRequestMap.get("responseEntity").toString();
```